# Import of android.hardware.camera2 cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-camera, eclipse-juno

On using import android.hardware.camera2. I am getting import cannot be resolved. How to clear this problem. I tried everything mentioned in other solution but I am not able to fix this up. Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question to show your code, please. Note that `android.hardware.camera2` itself is just a Java package; you import classes, not packages. If you literally have `import android.hardware.camera2;`, you would need to change that to `import android.hardware.camera2.*;` or something.

Comment: In my code I want to use new api android.hardware.Camera2. To use that I am trying to import it but I am not able to do so since it's snowing that "The import android. hardware. Camera2 cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I want to use new api android.hardware.Camera2

There is no Java class in Android named `android.hardware.Camera2`. There is a Java package named `android.hardware.camera2`. You are welcome to use classes out of that Java package, such as `android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager`.

> "The import android. hardware. Camera2 cannot be resolved"

That is because there is no Java class in Android named `android.hardware.Camera2`. There is a Java package named `android.hardware.camera2`. You are welcome to use classes out of that Java package, such as `android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager`, via `import` statements like:

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
```

or even:

```
import android.hardware.camera2.*;
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I was using android.hardware.Camera2 in place of android.hardware.camera2. Thanks